# Nginx not serving Django static files (Code Inside)

Tags: django, apache, nginx, debian, mod-wsgi

I will admit, I am a bit of a biased searcher... If I do not see a similar problem in the title of a post, I will likely not click it. That aside, I have done my research and cannot find a solid solution that works for me

**Problem**

I am using `Apache 2.4` and `mod_wsgi 4.5.22` as well as attempting to use `nginx 1.12.2-1~jessie` for serving my static files. My nginx setup does not seem to be serving my files.

**Setup**

Here is my *apache2* .conf file:

```
...
Alias /robots.txt  /home/user/web/domain.com/public_html/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /home/user/web/domain.com/public_html/favicon.ico

IncludeOptional /home/user/conf/web/apache2.domain.com.conf*

<Directory /home/user/web/domain.com/user/project/>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/web/domain.com/project/app/>
    AllowOverride All 
    Options +Includes
</Directory>

LoadModule wsgi_module "/root/.virtualenvs/user/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so"

WSGIDaemonProcess domain.com user=user group=user processes=2 threads=25
WSGIProcessGroup domain.com
```

```
WSGIPythonHome "/root/.virtualenvs/user"
```

Here is my *nginx* .conf file:

```
server {
listen      X.X.X.X:80;
server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
error_log  /var/log/apache2/domains/domain.com.error.log error;

location / { 
    proxy_pass      http://X.X.X.X:8080;
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf|webp|woff|txt|csv|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|odf|odp|ods|odt|pdf|psd|ai|eot|eps|ps|zip|tar|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|7z|aac|m4a|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|wma|3gp|avi|flv|m4v|mkv|mov|mpeg|mpg|wmv|exe|iso|dmg|swf)$ {
        root           /home/user/web/domain.com/public_html;
        access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/domain.com.log combined;
        access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/domain.com.bytes bytes;
        expires        max;
        try_files      $request_uri @fallback;
    }   
}   

location /error/ {
    alias   /home/user/web/domain.com/document_errors/;
}   

location @fallback {
    proxy_pass      http://X.X.X.X:8080;
}   

location /static {
    autoindex on; 
    alias /home/user/web/domain.com/project/app/static/;
}   

location ~ /\.ht    {return 404;}
location ~ /\.svn/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.git/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.hg/   {return 404;}
location ~ /\.bzr/  {return 404;}

include /home/user/conf/web/nginx.domain.com.conf*;}
```

**Errors**

I am not currently seeing any issues from this in my logs.

Comment: Why are you using nginx when Apache can handle hosting the static files? In most cases there is no reason to be putting nginx in front of Apache as a proxy if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: So through my research, to me at least, it seemed nginx would be best for scaling? But i tried doing this because, for some reason, i couldn’t get Apache to serve them up... i followed your documentation for mod_wsgi but it just wouldn’t work for me

Comment: Since you mentioned scaling you might not want to go this route, but WhiteNoise http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/ actually allows you to wrap your wsgi application so that it serves its own static files. It's supposed to be sufficient for small to medium traffic sites. I have it in deployment on one of my sites and it's incredibly simple. I also found S3 to be much simpler to get set up than nginx.

Comment: Unless you have a highly traffic'd site, you will not see any substantial difference between using just Apache and putting nginx in the mix. All you do by adding it is make your infrastructure more complicated when you perhaps don't need to.

Comment: Hmm... WhiteNoise may be a nice solution in the future once i face the need to scale, thank you for that. @GrahamDumpleton , considering my setup, what should i use for serving them with my Apache setup? I will readjust in the later morning and post my updated code if i cannot get it to work...

Comment: What is wrong with using only Apache? Why not go back and create a separate question about the issue you had when using only Apache? Whitenoise is not going to perform as well as using Apache. Also, you seemed to be very concerned about scaling yet on face value the mod_wsgi daemon configuration you are using is heading down the wrong direction as far as creating more threads. I would suggest you will gain more by paying better attention to things like that and bottlenecks in your own application code.

Comment: Thank you for the input, @GrahamDumpleton . I would refer back to my previous post you helped me on because now that mod_wsgi is running and i am using the socket-user option, i am again running into the permissions issue for the created socket

Comment: I got the impression you were saying you were having issues with static file handling in Apache from above, which is why you were looking at nginx. Anyway, you might be better taking this to the mod_wsgi mailing list if still having issues with socket owner. I am busy this week though, so responses may be slow.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion, @GrahamDumpleton   So the issue was originally static file problems due to nginx, but as per your suggestion, i went back to just using Apache since there is no current need to stress scaling. I will check out the mailing list and send you a message if i cannot get things working. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton , my issue has been resolved. For some reason, I went back and changed `socket-user=user` to `user=user` when I was having issues with nginx , but upon changing it back, my issue has been resolved!